# "Class does not support automation" error when i call Request.ServerVariables("remote_host")

Tags: cookies, asp-classic, vbscript, remote-host

I'm in the process of writing a basic cookie for an ecommerce site which is going to store the user's IP among other details.

We'll then record the pages they view in the database and pull out a list of recently viewed pages.

However i'm having an issue with the following code.

```
dim caller
caller = Response.Cookies("caller")
if caller = "" then 
    caller = Request.ServerVariables("remote_host")
end if
```

On running this, i get the following error message.

"Sun ONE ASP VBScript runtime (0x800A01AE)
Class does not support automation"

Any ideas? Google has nothing obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be Request.Cookies when checking the value.:

```
dim caller
caller = Request.Cookies("caller")
if caller = "" then 
    caller = Request.ServerVariables("remote_host")
end if
```